# Is there an inclusion of ideals $(xy)\subset(x-a,y-b)$ in $K[x,y]$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra

Let $a,b\in K$ where $K$ is algebraically closed field. I'm trying to determine for which $a$ and $b$ there is an inclusion
$$(xy)\subset(x-a,y-b)$$
of ideals in $K[x,y]$.

Suppose that $a=0$. Given any $p(x,y)xy\in (xy)$ we see that $(p(x,y)y)x+0(y-b)\in(x,y-b)$ and by symmetry we have an inclusion if $a\neq0$ or $b\neq0$. If both are zero we have an inclusion as well.

The remaining case is when $a\neq0$ and $b\neq0$. I have an idea that there is not going to be an inclusion and here is why: If we assume by contradiction that $xy=f(x,y)(x-a)+g(x,y)(y-b)$ then if we consider the root $(a,b)$ for the right-hand side, we get an equation $ab=0$. If this is not a contradiction then it certainly seems like a hint that the inclusion does not hold, but I'm unsure how to proceed from here.

I would very much appreciate comments on this strategy/observation and if it does not yield anything about the inclusion I would also appreciate any hints that could lead one in the right direction. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your argument looks ok to me, do you have a specific question on this or are you just looking for confirmation of your result? You can also check if this inclusion holds true using computer algebra software such as SAGE, Magma,...

Comment: $(x-a,y-b)$ is a maximal ideal and thus if $xy$ belongs, one of $x$ or $y$ belongs. Then, one of $a$ or $b$ must be zero.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your approach is fine, although it is a bit roundabout. First, it is worth noting that
$$(xy)\subset(x-a,y-b)\qquad\Leftrightarrow\qquad xy\in(x-a,y-b).$$
Now for your first case, with either $a=0$ or $b=0$, it suffices to see that then either $x\in(x-a,y-b)$ or $y\in(x-a,y-b)$, respectively, and hence $xy\in(x-a,y-b)$.

For the remaining case with $ab\neq0$, you correctly deduce that if $xy\in(x-a,y-b)$ then
$$xy=f(x,y)(x-a)+g(x,y)(y-b),$$
for some polynomials $f(x,y),g(x,y)\in K[x,y]$. Indeed plugging in $(a,b)$ yields
$$ab=f(a,b)(a-a)+g(a,b)(b-b)=0.$$
Now you are done; this directly contradicts the assumption that $ab\neq0$, so $xy\notin(x-a,y-b)$.

---

You could reverse the order of the two cases to get a slightly shorter variant:

> Suppose $(xy)\subset(x-a,y-b)$. Then $xy\in(x-a,y-b)$ hence also
>   $$xy-x(y-b)-b(x-a)=ab\in(x-a,y-b).$$
>   Because $(x-a,y-b)\cap K=0$ this implies $ab=0$, so either $a=0$ or $b=0$.
>
> Of course conversely, if either $a=0$ or $b=0$ then either 
>   $$x\in(x-a,y-b)\qquad\text{ or }\qquad y\in(x-a,y-b),$$
>   and hence $xy\in(x-a,y-b)$.